# Geometric Notation found in Mathematical Methods For Physics And Engineering

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, notation

In the book *Mathematical Methods For Physics And Engineering*, there is a section proving compound-angle properties; this section is pretty readable for me until page 12. It states:
$$\cos B=x'=TN+NP=MR+NP$$
$$    =OR\sin A+RP\cos A=\sin(A+B)\sin A+\cos(A+B)\cos A;$$

[image]

Earlier, the book explained that $Oxy$ and $Ox'y'$ are the two coordinate systems which were to be referenced from then on in the proof. This means, in my mind, that $x'$ is obviously the x-axis in the second coordinate system, but then if this were true the statement $\cos B=x'$ would be a meaningless statement, no? Secondly, I'm a bit confused about what $OR\sin A$ means. $TM$ seems to mean the line segment from $T$ to $M$ but $OR\sin A$ doesn't seem to have any geometric meaning. Is it the scaled version of $OR$ and if so, why is it being scaled? I am pretty new to this so I'm sorry if this seems trivial to you guys.

Comment: Is there a diagram in the book to aid your visualization? $x'$ should be a length measured from the origin, and $OR \sin A$ should be a height.

Comment: @player3236 There is but I don't have a picture of it. Lukily Google books has a preview of page 11 where the diagram is. https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mathematical_Methods_for_Physics_and_Eng/ol6pZCDG5SYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @player3236 Like I said though $x'$ is the axis and not a segment. $ORsinA$ is still hard for me to visualize as well.

Comment: I think I found the diagram. Can I add it in your question so others may see as well?

Comment: Go ahead, I would very much appreciate it. You might want to use this (probably illegal)  copy though. It is a lot sharper: https://luiarthur.github.io/assets/ams211/mathbook.pdf.

Comment: @player3236 Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, $x'$ stands for the distance between the origin and the foot of the perpendicular drawn from $P$ to the $x'$-axis (or the projection/shadow of $OP$ to the $x'$-axis). Hence this length is equal to $TP$ and $MR + NP$. Here the same word "$x'$" is used in two different contexts: $x'$ is a variable, and the $x'$-axis is a coordinate axis.

As to "$OR\sin A$", consider $\triangle OMR$. We have, by construction, $OM \perp MR$ and $\angle MOR = A$. Hence by definition of $\sin$, we have $\sin A = \dfrac {MR}{OR}$. This gives $MR = OR\sin A$.

Comment: Ahh, I see, excellent!! Thank you very much for helping me not only with the answer but with making the question too. You have been helpful throughout this entire process, I am very grateful.